# calculating totals for a database tables and combining results from different tables

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server-2008

i have several tables in my database
-Orders
-OrderDetials
-customers
etc

i need to calculate each table's row total and combine it in a single output that
has only the table names and row total of each table

is there anyone that can help me with some advise, I've been struggling a lot.

Comment: mysql or sql server 2008?

Comment: maybe it's sql server 2008 with a mysql linked server

Comment: What have you tried? Can you please specify whether you mean MySQL, SQL Server, or both?

Answer (score 2):

For SQL Server, this is going to be *FAR* more efficient than `COUNT(*)` which - while being more accurate depending on the volume on the system - can be quite a performance hog (and if the system is volatile the count is not going to be accurate by the time all the unions collect their information anyway):

```
SELECT t.name, SUM(p.rows)
  FROM sys.tables AS t
  INNER JOIN sys.partitions AS p
  ON t.[object_id] = p.[object_id]
  GROUP BY t.name
  ORDER BY t.name;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this in Microsoft SQL Server 2008:

```
DECLARE @Tables TABLE
(
   TableName VARCHAR(50),
   RowCount INT
)

INSERT INTO @Tables
SELECT
   'Customers',
   COUNT(*) AS RowCount
FROM
   Customers

INSERT INTO @Tables
SELECT
   'Orders',
   COUNT(*) AS RowCount
FROM
   Orders

etc...

SELECT
   *
FROM
   @Tables
```

Comment: Just note that manually deriving the count this way can be quite expensive and can actually block other readers and writers. For large tables with heavy access, I suspect that `sys.partitions` or `sys.dm_db_partition_stats` will be more reliable (and much faster) than if you've blocked a bunch of inserts or deletes by having to scan the entire table to fetch the count.

Comment: Agreed. Unfortunately the OP hasn't given us a whole lot to go off of.

Answer (score 1):

I believe something like this will work:

```
SELECT 'Table 1 Name', count(column_to_sum) from table_1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Table 2 Name', count(column_to_sum) from table_2
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'Table 3 Name', count(column_to_sum) from table_3
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'Table 4 Name', count(column_to_sum) from table_4
```

Here's a link to the [docs on the `UNION` command in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html) for more info.

Comment: replace `sum` with `count` and `UNION` with `UNION ALL`(performance, tablenames are unique). Apart from that, this works for SQL-Server **and** MySql.

Comment: Thanks -- I've edited the answer to take into account your comment. I misread the question and thought he meant sum of the values, not count. Thanks again!

Comment: I strongly recommend using `'` not `"` for string delimiters. Not sure about MySQL but `"` can cause issues for SQL Server.

Comment: @AaronBertrand You're right. Thanks for the comment I've corrected the query.

Answer (score 0):

If you use SQL Server 2008* and have clustered indexes on all tables, you could perform this query:

```
select o.name, i.rowcnt
from sys.sysobjects o
join sys.sysindexes i 
    on i.id = o.id and i.indid = 1 -- only clustered indexes
where o.xtype='U' -- only objects of type 'User Table'
```

**) Unclear for the moment, judging by the question tags.*

Comment: Why would you use backward compatibility views from SQL Server 2000 instead of the much preferred catalog views `sys.tables` and `sys.partitions`? Also what if the table doesn't have a clustered index? Heaps are tables too.